# Unable to hide the virtual keyboard of SearchView iconfiedbydefault(false)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview, optionmenu

I have a search view which is set as expanded by default with default search query but i don't want the virtual keyboard.In below code i tried to hide keyboard in **onCreateOptionsMenu** but still keyboard is visible.

```
imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    item.expandActionView();
    mSearchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setQuery(query, true);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I am using sherlock search view widget. any suggestion to hide the virtual keyboard.What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Inspired by Parnit's answer, I've found a better method, which also works and is more beautiful:

```
mSearchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to open the keyboard again?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I added the better solution on top, but also kept the old answer as a reference.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                  searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
```

Original Answer: I programmed using a setOnQueryTextListener. When the searchview is hidden the keyboard goes away and then when it is visible again the keyboard does not pop back up.

```
    //set query change listener
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            /**
             * hides and then unhides search tab to make sure keyboard disappears when query is submitted
             */
                  searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }

     });
```

Comment: This works for me after trying tens of methods! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: +1. Or just put `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` on android manifest if no need to set keyboard hidden manually.

Answer (score 1):

add the below line in the manifest for particular Activity.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

Comment: For which purpose `adjustPan` is here? Wouldn't be enough just using `stateHidden` alone?

Comment: by using adjustPan current focus is never obscured by the keyboard .. for more info go here.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 1):

simple solution its work for my
add to XML:

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Manifest:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

In class open and close the  keyboard:

```
   @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action buttons
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.search:
         //TODO Whatever
          search.clearFocus();
         //Open and close the  keyboard
          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
          imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
          return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

u just have to use:
 "object(edittext, searchview, etc)".clearfocus() ;

use it after u generate a search or an action. Example: in the method OnQueryTextListener, after that i use a search. For searchview.

Comment: How does this improve on the other answers that already mention that function?