# How to hide android keyboard in search view

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I've used search view in my application. I wonder how to hide the keyboard when i hit the search button on the search view? I have to use the back button to view the results.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851964/android-searchview-onclick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184703/unable-to-hide-the-virtual-keyboard-of-searchview-iconfiedbydefaultfalse?answertab=votes#tab-top) also

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard in Android Honeycomb searchView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409288/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-android-honeycomb-searchview)

Comment: why did you not choose this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20867923/4548520 ? it's correct one

Answer (score 46):

Here is a similar question:
[How to dismiss keyboard in Android SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409288/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-android-honeycomb-searchview)

```
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      // Do search.
      searchView.clearFocus();
      return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
private void hideKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

call it on search button click listener

Answer (score 0):

you can hide it by

```
mSearchView.setIconified(true);
```